# How to force Fedora 12 to start to text mode?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, vga, fedora-12

I have a problem with my newly installed ATI driver so my Fedora 12 boots to a frozen graphic mode display.

I need to force it to boot to text mode interface to start adjusting my X configuration. What to do?

This is a new Fedora 12 installation without any change to GRUB etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you first start your computer, the GRUB screen (where you choose your Operating System) appears. Select the Fedora that you want to boot into, but press the <kbd>a</kbd> key instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will see a line somewhat like the following:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.9-1.667 ro root=LABEL=/ acpi=on rhgb quiet
```

Add the number of your runlevel to the end of that line, and then press Enter. For example, to boot into text-only mode, the line would look like:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.9-1.667 ro root=LABEL=/ acpi=on rhgb quiet 3
```

You will then boot into the new runlevel this time only.

More about runlevels: http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#runlevel

Comment: This worked for me in Fedora 22, though I had to hit 'e' instead of 'a' and scroll down to find the "quiet" parameter. I added a '3' after the quiet, pressed Ctrl-X, and it booted into text mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when booting to show the GRUB menu. Then select the kernel you care about, hit <kbd>A</kbd>, remove `rhgb` if it shows on the line, then go to the end and type <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I would accept your answer too but I can accept only one answer. Also I can't give you +1 because I am too poor. Thanks very much Mr rich :)

Comment: @mmonem - Here, +1 from me then ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since this thread is the top most on Goole.com when searching for *How to boot Fedora to text mode* I add this guidance for newer versions of Fedora.

To **boot into text mode** in never versions of **Fedora 16+** using **GRUB2** the steps are slightly differren:

1. When you first start your computer, the GRUB screen (where you choose your Operating System) appears
2. Select the Fedora that you want to boot into, and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key instead of pressing <kbd><strike>Enter</strike></kbd> to edit selected item
3. Scroll down to find the parameter `quiet` parameter and add white space and number three just after the quiet parameter, ie `quiet 3`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to start
5. Fedora will reboot into the text mode

Tested on Fedora 20, 22, 29

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions, pressing A won't work any more - hit now "E" to enter edit mode.
A multi-line configuration will appear, but there you will find again those same entries "rhgb" and "quiet", just remove them and put a 3 instead.

Then pressing F10 will take you to the (now usefully verbose) boot process, landing in a (text) login prompt. Done.

*(Tested with Fedora 20).*

Comment: The question, however, is about Fedora 12, as it says three times over.  Fedora didn't switch to GRUB2, with the different keyboard commands, until Fedora 16.